# Nothing shown If replace current fragment with another one

Tags: android, android-layout

I have such layout:

**frame_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/items"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Next, in FragmentActivity I do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
String tag = MyListFragment.class.getName();
MyListFragment fragment = (MyListFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
 if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = new MyListFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.items, fragment, tag);
 }
 else {
    ft.replace(R.id.items, fragment, tag);
 }
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
 ft.commit();
```

When I call this code once, fragment shown perfectly! But, when it called twice I see no content!
After some investigation, I found that problem's caused by this:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
```

E.g., when it is called once, fragment content is perfectly shown! But I need to call `setContentView` a lot of times to show another fragments.

Where's the mistake?

P.S. It's possible to make `MyListFragment` hardcoded into XML, but this does not fit to me, because I need to replace layout contents with other fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody answers, I found another solution: keep layout for every frame and show/hide them.

That's how I did it.... Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container2"
 android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

That's how I show fragment2 (belongs to container2) in fragment activity:

```
findViewById(R.id.container1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
findViewById(R.id.container2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
String tag = MyFragment.class.getName();
Fragment fragment = (Fragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
if (fragment == null) {
   fragment = new MyFragment();
   ft.add(R.id.container2, fragment, tag);
}

ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```